# POST method returns 415

Tags: 8

Trying to create a node `page` through web-service.But returns **415 Unsupported media type**

This is how I have done

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think we need more information. What modules do you have installed on the site? Depending on the rest module installed, this could require hal+json as the content type. The answer below mentions a Core issue that was fixed several months before Drupal 8.0.0 release. Are you using a supported Drupal 8.0.x release?

Comment: I am using drupal 8.0.1. I have used the default rest module. Just used rest ui for ui. Thats all

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example raw data you should be sending (don't send it as form data):

```
{
  "type":[{"target_id":"article"}],
  "title":[{"value":"Hello World"}]
}
```

You do not need to send the `Accept` header, because that no longer matters because of the `_format=json` query string. And in this case, when successful, it will return a 201 so you can disregard the `_format` query string.

The POST to `?q=entity/node` is correct, but don't forget to send an `X-CSRF-Token` header with a value that can be retrieved here: `?q=rest/session/token`

Comment: I come from Google and had problems with hal+json or hal_json all the time. After I switched everything to pure JSON and removed `_links` from my data payload, everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently trying to send form-data encoded values? If you claim the send json, then you actually need to send a valid json structure. This is a service, not a form.

Create a new in the UI that looks like one that you want to create, then access it using GET through rest with the same format. Adjust that, e.g. remove the ID and UUID and then use that as the template/value to POST.